# question about class and method inheritance

Tags: ruby, class

I have the following code and I am trying to understand why I can't get [:hoge] instead I get an empty response.
Could anyone help me understand why this is?

```rb
class Foo
  def self.fuga
     pp Foo.public_instance_methods(false)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  fuga

   def hoge
    p "fuga"
   end
end

Bar.fuga
=> []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an empty array because at `Foo.public_instance_methods` you call `public_instance_methods` on `Foo` and `Foo` doesn't have any public instance methods (only `Bar` does).

If you change that line to `self.public_instance_methods` it would work as expected.

```
class Foo
  def self.fuga
    pp self.public_instance_methods(false)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  fuga

  def hoge
    p "fuga"
  end
end

Bar.fuga
#=> [:hoge]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in the class definition of `Bar`, `fuga` is executed and prints an empty array (because `hoge` has not yet been defined) and that `self.` in `self.public_instance_methods(false)` is not needed as `self` is the receiver when there is no explicit receiver.  Also, `require 'pp'` is needed.